# angular2 fullstack app with nodejs backend server in one project

Tags: node.js, git, angular

Just trying to figure out whats the best way to build an angular 2 fullstack app, where the nodejs server is serving a rest/graphql endpoint on the one hand and on the other hand the angular 2 app. I'd like to build on a structure which in future will also allow server side rendering.

Are there any best practices for this?

My idea so far is to have the nodejs as backend app also serving the angular 2 app. However this seems not night.

```
.
/src             # node server src code
/node_modules    # npm installed libs for node server
/public/         # angular 2 app
  node_modules/  # npm installed libs for angular 2 app
  app/           # angular 2 application code
  index.html
  app.js
```

However I'm not sure if this is a good practise? How would you handle this with npm? Just init two projects and install dependencies either in the root directory or the public directory?

Is there any better solution for this like building the angular app into the public folder and only serve the builded app?

Answer (score 0):

I would build 2 different project (and 2 repos if using Git)

One for the backend api (nodeJS / Express / DB /...)

And the other one in the front using nodeJS also for the server side rendering and for serving the index.html

Comment: ok, if so, how would you bring those together for development? Just run both separately and hardlink urls? How would would you deploy and deliver them later from one nodejs server? I'd like to only run one elastic beanstalk environment later.